# Word-frequency and statistics

Tags: natural-language, discrete-data, frequency

I am new to statistics and am wondering how I can apply it in linguistics. There is a conjunction in a corpus that 902 times (.91) conjoins sub-clausal units, and 91 (.09) times clausal units. How would I go about using statistical methods to argue that this distribution did not arise by chance? Do I need data from another conjunction that would show how conjunctions are "normally distributed"? What test would I use in this case?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer this question without some additional information (for instance, defining the basic terms you are using); you should also edit your question so the title reflects the specific content of the question.

Comment: That is the problem: I don't know what additional information I should be providing. What do you mean the basic terms? There is a word that occurs in total 993 times. In 902 cases (or .91) that word occurs before something smaller than a clause. In 91 times (or .09) it occurs before a clause. What other terms should I include?

Comment: Your phrase, did not arise by chance, leads to hypothesis testing. Which is a method to show that a particular assertion, hypothesis, is unlikely to have happened by chance. The data you give us, in isolation, can not be used to infer very much. You might have to analyse other conjunctions and compare and contrast them, in an attempt to understand the general behaviour of conjunctions. Then you might be able to infer something about this particular conjunction, or it's use in this particular corpus as opposed to other conjunctions in this and other corpuses. More information needed :)

Comment: Exactly what question are you trying to answer?  What difference are you looking for?  What are you trying to prove?  It is not clear from the original question.

Comment: As the other commenters have said, there isn't enough information to give a strong answer to your question. That said, years ago I worked in a lab studying neurolinguistics and had to do some similar analyses (related to frequency counts in a corpus). Essentially, the literature at the time had no consistent recommendations as to what to do. Based on my own experience doing that research and consulting with other researchers, I found the best thing to do is to use a bootstrap method to construct hypothesis tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to be able to say that the unbalanced split is not due to chance, you could do a z test to compare the proportion .91 to the null hypothesis of .5  (Alternatively, you could do the test on the .09 proportion; it is the same mathematically.)  The details on conducting such a statistical test are in most elementary statistics books (under one-sample test of proportions) and on-line (e.g. http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic116457.files/Review_Session_Slides_-_Part_2_-_Yves.pdf).